# Apache Spark : spark executor pod isn't able to pull docker image from a registry/repo

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I'm new to Apache Spark.

I'm trying to run a spark session using **pyspark**.
I have configured to have 2 executor nodes for it.
Now both of the executor nodes needs to pull my custom built spark image which is in a repo.

Below is the configuration in python for my spark session/job

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sparkpi-test1'
).master("k8s://https://kubernetes.default:443"
).config("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "\<repo\>"
).config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.caCertFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt"
).config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.oauthTokenFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"
).config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName", "spark-driver-0"
).config("spark.executor.instances", 2
).config("spark.driver.host", "test"
).config("spark.driver.port", "20020"
).config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
).config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false"
).config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12:0.12.1,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2"
).config("spark.kubernetes.node.selector.testNodeCategory", "ondemand"
).getOrCreate()
```

> sparkpi-test1-2341a185c8144b60-exec-1            0/1
> ImagePullBackOff    0          5h17m
> sparkpi-test1-2341a185c8144b60-exec-2            0/1
> ImagePullBackOff    0          5h17m

So, Correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.
I'm trying to setup Spark in my existing kubernetes cluster using my custom built spark image in some repo.
I mentioned the same in configuration in my python file.

> ).config("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "<repo>"

According to docs

```
Container image to use for the Spark application. This is usually of the form example.com/repo/spark:v1.0.0. This configuration is required and must be provided by the user, unless explicit images are provided for each different container type.
```

Why is my executor node failing to pull the image from registry ?
How do I pull it manually for executor node for the  time being ?

Just for reference Find the below error messages

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I guess the above error message is because my executor pods didn't create succesfully.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Comment: @Koedlt Thank you for the advice. Made the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve got it.
I was using terraform to build all the resources.
.tfstate file got changed and is causing the pods to have these errors

Clearing terraform cache got my problem solved.

To clean terraform cache
run

```
rm -rf .terraform
```

In your terraform directory